# Does the Facebook Graph API have a versioning scheme?

Tags: facebook, api

The title says it all. I've perused the online docs, the GitHub repos, the code itself. Does any of it have a version string? (Does it really matter?)

Comment: Here's a link (although not from facebook) http://www.lexicalscope.com/blog/2012/03/12/how-are-rest-apis-versioned/

Comment: Yours is a better answer, make it official and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do now.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog for the new version schema.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

PS: SO community also requires the answer to be full of facts and complete, with some proofs and links, but in this case I cannot give a link to a documentation page that doesn't exists.

Comment: Actually I think it does - with iOS version number buried in the code somewhere...

Comment: @psoft: how this question is related to iOS?

Answer (score 1):

They do not.

> We do have a versioning mechanism for breaking changes. They are called Platform Migrations. However, we don't keep old versions around for too long so we aren't slowed down by old systems. 
>   - http://qr.ae/vBse7